# How to make AmChart follow synchronize with video element

Tags: javascript, django, html, amcharts

I am currently working on a project that uses https://www.amcharts.com and I am trying to synchronize a `<video>` element's "currentTime" to the chart's cursor. Similar to this example with audio: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/sync-chart-cursor-html5-audio/

In the example above, the audio emits the currentTime event with the current audio time, then converts the time to a format to an argument in `chart.chartCursor.showCursorAt(time)` In my example below, once the currentTime emits, the cursor goes all the way to the end of the graph and stays there.

How can I make it so the video's "currentTime" hover's over the corresponding time in the chart?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {

    "type": "stock",
    "theme": "light",

    "categoryAxesSettings": {
      "minPeriod": "ss", // set minimum to milliseconds
      "groupToPeriods": [ 'ss' ] // specify period grouping
    },

    "dataSets": [ 
    {% for l, c in labels %}
      {
        "title": "{{ l|safe }}",
        "color": "{{ c }}",
        "fieldMappings": [ {
          "fromField": "prominence",
          "toField": "prominence"
        } ],
        "dataLoader": {
          "url": "/data/csv/calc/{{ l|quote }}.csv",
          "format": "csv",
          "delimiter": ",",
          "useColumnNames": true,
          "skip": 1
        },
        "categoryField": "time"
      }{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    ],

    "panels": [ {
        "title": "Prominence",
        "percentHeight": 70,

        "stockGraphs": [ {
          "id": "g1",
          "valueField": "prominence",
          "lineThickness": 2,
          "bullet": "round",
          "comparable": true,
          "compareField": "prominence",
          "balloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[prominence]]</b>",
          "compareGraphBalloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[prominence]]</b>"
        } ],

        "stockLegend": {
          "periodValueTextRegular": "[[prominence.close]]",
          "periodValueTextComparing": "[[prominence.close]]"
        }
      }
    ],
    "chartCursorSettings": {
      "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
      "categoryBalloonDateFormats": [ {
        "period": "ss",
        "format": "JJ:NN:SS"
      } ]
    },

    "dataSetSelector": {
      "position": "left"
    }
    ,

    "panelsSettings": {
      "usePrefixes": true
    }
  });

  chart.parseDates = true;
  chart.dataDateFormat = "JJ:NN:SS";
  chart.panelsSettings.recalculateToPercents = "never";

  $("#video").on(
    "timeupdate", 
    function(event){
    var dur = moment.duration(this.currentTime,"seconds").format("hh:mm:ss",{ trim: false })
            console.log(dur);
    chart.chartCursors[0].showCursorAt(dur)
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showCursorAt` needs the converted category value since you're using string timestamps. AmCharts converts strings to JavaScript `Date` objects, so you want the `Date` object rather than the string format (note that the audio demo also uses `Date` objects)

In addition to that, AmCharts converts time-only dates (`JJ:NN:SS`) to dates starting from January 1st, 1900. You'll need to ensure your conversion matches. Since you're using moment:

```
   var newTime = moment(
     moment
       .duration(this.currentTime, "seconds")
       .format("1900-01-01 hh:mm:ss", { trim: false })
   ).toDate();
   chart.chartCursors[0].showCursorAt(newTime);
```

You can also use [`AmCharts.stringToDate`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCharts#stringToDate):

```
  var newTime = AmCharts.stringToDate(
    moment
      .duration(this.currentTime, "seconds")
      .format("hh:mm:ss", { trim: false }),
    "JJ:NN:SS"
  );
  chart.chartCursors[0].showCursorAt(newTime);
```

You also need to set [`equalSpacing`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/CategoryAxesSettings#equalSpacing) to true in your `categoryAxisSettings` to prevent the cursor from jittering.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/2d1b9cfb400127738571c55bf56f357e?editors=0010)

Unrelated notes -

It is recommended that you set settings like `dataDateFormat`, `recalculateToPercents` and `parseDates` inside the makeChart call rather than right after the call or you'll run into timing issues. Also note that `parseDates` is implied in a stock chart and is not required.